# Authentication Microsoft OneDrive REST services Java/Ionic 2

Tags: java, spring, rest, ionic2, onedrive

I'm trying to authenticate to Microsoft OneDrive, with REST service, in my app, using Java for backend and Ionic 2. The authentication now works if I call my service directly from Chrome.
I post the code:

```
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getToken";

@RequestMapping(value = { "/getAccess" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void authorizationFlow(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
        String authURL = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID
                + "&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.offline_access%20wl.skydrive_update&response_type=code&redirect_uri="
                + REDIRECT_URI;
        response.sendRedirect(authURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.severe(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/getToken" }, params = { "code" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getToken(@RequestParam("code") String code)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        logger.info("Auth CODE: " + code);
        String url = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&" + "redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI + "&"
                + "client_secret=" + SECRET + "&" + "code=" + code + "&" + "grant_type=authorization_code";
        logger.info(url + urlParameters);

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        logger.info("REQUEST SENT. Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        String risposta = response.toString();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(risposta);
        String token = json.get("access_token").toString();

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        file.write(json.toJSONString());

        logger.info("\nTOKEN:\n" + token);

        file.flush();
        file.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("ERRORE: " + e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I call the first service, I get a code, and I make a redirect on the second service, which provides me a json with the token, to be used for all other calls. Up to this everything works.
The problem comes using Ionic 2. I post the code:

The service:

```
getAuthOneDrive(){
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAccess';
  var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  return response;
}
```

The component:

```
getAuthOneDrive(){
  this.cloudServiceAuthentication.getAuthOneDrive().subscribe(
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => console.log('getAuthOneDrive Complete')
  );
}
```

And my proxy, that I've configured in ionic.config.json:

```
{
  "name": "C2C",
  "app_id": "c6203dd8",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8080/"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I try to call the same service (http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAcces), from the app in Ionic2, by a click on a button, I get this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAccess. Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAccess' to 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=ae9573ba-6bc0-4a87-8…ype=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getToken' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I really tried everything. If someone can give me a help I would be grateful. Thanks! ;)

EDIT:

This is what I've tried to do: 
1- add "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' header, I've got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAccess. Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getAccess' to 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=ae9573ba-6bc0-4a87-8…ype=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getToken' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.
```

2- do not use response.sendRedirect in the first service, but satisfy the request with HttpsURLConnection or Spring RestTemplate; 
3- trying to call the Microsoft service directly from Ionic;
4- use the Spring annotation @CrossOrigin, but I've got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by modifying the first service /getAccess, adding the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin and using my REDIRECT_URI and no longer the sendRedirect which gave problems.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = { "/getAccess" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void authenticate() throws IOException {
    try {
        OneDriveSDK sdk = OneDriveFactory.createOneDriveSDK(CLIENT_ID, SECRET, REDIRECT_URI,
                OneDriveScope.READWRITE);
        String url = sdk.getAuthenticationURL();
        logger.info(url);
        openWebpage(url);
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        logger.info("REQUEST SENT. Response Code : " + responseCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin requests are restricted by the browser for security reasons.  Take a look at [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for a detailed explaination of how this works.

Setting the following header should allow you to work around the issue in development:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Just make sure you remove this header (or at least restrict it beyond '*') in your production deployment.

Comment: If I add this header, which had already tried to do, I get this error:     "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=ae9573ba-6bc0-4a87-8…ype=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/CloudToCloud/onedrive/getToken. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." I think the reason is that the Microsoft service does not accept this header.